# Setting up Visual Studio 2017 for a C learning project

Tags: c, visual-studio, ide, solution

Just got a "The C programming language, 2nd edition" and I'm struggling to make a solution using Visual Studio 2017 that could hold all exercises I do in one project. I don't want to create a new project for every single exercise in book.
How would I go around creating a solution with either multiple main() or calling upon different .c in main?

Say that first exercise is to create a program printing a conversion table from Fahrenheit to Celsius and next exercise involves using getchar().
Is that manageable in Visual Studio or should I pick another IDE.

Comment: Suggestion: Don't use MSVS for any of C learning. Use the industry standard `gcc`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why not?

Comment: @stackptr Because MS C compiler does not respect any C standards.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Doesn't Microsoft C use C89?

Comment: @EugeneSh. to the best of my knowledge MSVC does not have C compiler. They have C++ compiler.

Comment: @SergeyA You can make it work in some C-ish way...

Comment: @stackptr The current one is c11. There were c90, C99 in between.

Comment: It is a C compiler if the file extension is c.  You can also force it to build in C with /TC.  @Karim - It will be one project per exercise.  One project creates one executable.  If you group all you code into one project, how will you know which program you are executing?  You will find the same problem with codeblocks, eclipse, codelite, geany or any other IDE.  If you do not wish to use an IDE, then it is a different story.